# Pydantic model to have a dictionary with a list of strings

Tags: python, pydantic

I want my input to the class to be in the following format:

```
{'key_name1' : ['str1','str2'],
 'key_name2' : ['str1','str2']}
```

I've tried the following using Pydantic however it says `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class blabla(BaseModel):
    val : dict[list[str]]
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
```

How can I implement type checks using pydantic for this case?

Comment: Can you show us how do you want to instantiate your pydantic object and what is the expected result then?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate class with init parameter `bla` which is of type `BlaBla`, where `BlaBla` is a Pydantic `BaseModel`. For example:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel


class BlaItem(BaseModel):
    item1: str
    item2: str


class BlaBla(BaseModel):
    val: List[BlaItem]


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bla: BlaBla):
        self.bla: BlaBla
    

b = Foo(
    bla=BlaBla(
        val=[
            BlaItem(item1="string1", item2="string2"),
            BlaItem(item1="string1", item2="string2")
        ]
    )
)
```

Of Course, if you don't want the extra class (it's just a personal preference). You can also initiate an `BlaBla` object like this:

```
b = BlaBla(
        val=[
            BlaItem(item1="string1", item2="string2"),
            BlaItem(item1="string1", item2="string2")
        ]
    )
```